# Why can't IntHolder be found in JDK 14?

Tags: java, java-14

When I type `IntHolder`, it prompts me to Cannot resolve symbol `IntHolder`.My JDK is 14.And I can't find it in the JDK documentation.Will some classes or others disappear with the JDK version update?

Comment: Which `IntHolder` are you talking about?

Comment: are you looking for `org.omg.CORBA.IntHolder`?

Comment: @Naman Yes, I am looking for `org.omg.CORBA.IntHolder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CORBA modules containing the [`org.omg.CORBA.IntHolder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/IntHolder.html) were removed with JDK 11. https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320

you can still add the content as dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.corba/glassfish-corba-orb
https://github.com/javaee/glassfish-corba

Answer (score -5):

Generally this issue should not be there , as java don't really remove the classes it just deprecates it. May be you should try re-installing JAVA .

It was deprecated with JDK 11

Comment: that is not correct. The package was deprecated in JDK 9 and completely removed from the JDK with JDK 11, as you can read in the link to JEP320 in my answer. Java is not always 100% backwards compatible to all packages.